# What happens when a L2 packet has same source and destination MAC address

Tags: network-programming, mac-address, osi

When a L2 packet has the same source and destination MAC address does it go out of the stack of the host to the switch and come back to the same interface ? Or is the L2 packet with the same source and destination MAC moved from the TX ring of the host to the RX ring and the above layer picks it up ?

If it goes to the switch, if at all it is legitimate, shouldn't the switch drop the packet as it could mean an attack ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, it depends on the switch. In general a switch in the network will not forward a packet out of port on which it was received, whether it was destined for the same MAC address or not.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. Is the kernel then expected to move the L2 packet from the TX ring to the RX ring ? A clarification here would make the loop of understanding complete